# Is it correct to say "whose history goes back" when talking about a technology?

Tags: sentence-usage

Is it correct to say "whose history goes back" in a sentence talking about a certain technology?

Comment: Can you please give the whole sentence ?

Comment: Waiting for the whole sentence, but you'll probably end up using "[...] the history **of which** goes back". See: http://www.grammarbank.com/whose-of-which-of-whom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer for this question is **"Yes, but..."**

One of the problems with English is that we have the words *who* and *which*, which are used for persons and objects or inanimate things respectively, like

> The lady who was there
>   The technology which was invented

and we have the word *whose*, which we can use like

> The lady, whose horse was tied up in front of the house...

but we don't have a word like "which's"!

> The technology, <strike>which's</strike> history goes back five decades...

So if we need to use a word like *whose*, but for an inanimate thing, we have only two choices:

- Use *whose*: "The technology, whose history goes back five decades..."
- Rephrase it so we don't have to: "The technology, the history of which goes back five decades..."

Personally I think using *whose* for inanimate objects sounds wrong, and I would rather rephrase it, but there are many famous authors who have used *whose* for inanimate objects, and there are many people who think rephrasing it sounds worse.

References:

- [Can “whose” refer to an inanimate object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/can-whose-refer-to-an-inanimate-object)
- [Whose for Inanimate Objects](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/whose-for-inanimate-objects)